# When is cdf $F_{X_1+\dots+X_n}(c)$ of sum of iid zero mean random variables decreasing in sample size $n$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with mean zero (e.g., $N(0,1)$). Let $n > m$ and $c \geq 0$. I want to show that
$$ P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq c \right) \leq P \left( \sum_{i=1}^m X_i \leq c \right).$$
In view of existing concentration bounds like Hoeffding's inequlity which scale with the the length of the sequence, i.e. $n$ and $m$, I would think that the above statement should hold.

**Edit:** Since it was pointed out that this doesn't hold for specific cases where $n$ and $m$ are small and the distribution of $X_i$ is discrete, assume that $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are Gaussian and $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: In a new answer, I just showed that the inequality holds for any log-concave distributions with zero mean, including the standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the gaussian assumption, we can calculate analytically the two probabilities, it suffices to notice that $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\sim \sqrt{n}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\le c  \right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\mathcal{N}(0,1)\le \frac{c}{\sqrt n}  \right) = \Phi\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt n}\right)$$

As $\frac{c}{\sqrt n} <\frac{c}{\sqrt m}$  for $c \ge 0$ and $n >m$, we have
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\le c  \right)\le \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^mX_i\le c  \right)$$

Comment: More generally, wouldn't it then always suffice for $n$ to be sufficiently large? In the sense that, there always exists an $n$ such that for any $c > 0$ and $m < n$, we have $\mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq c \right) \leq \mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=1}^m X_i \leq c \right)$.

Comment: @FelixP. Yes, we can say that for any $c>0$, for all $n$ such that $m<n$, we have this inequality. This statement holds true for both $n,m$ large and small, thanks to the gaussian assumption.

Comment: Wouldn't it also hold more generally for any sub-Gaussian distribution? (Not specifically only for Gaussian)

Answer (score 2):

Take $X_i$ such that $X_i=-2$ with probability $\dfrac{1}{3}$ and $X_i=1$ with probability $\dfrac{2}{3}$. A direct calculation shows that $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0$.

Take $n=2, m=1$, $c=0$.

Obviously, $$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^m X_i \leq c\right)=P(X_1\leq 0)=P(X_1=-2)=\dfrac{1}{3}$$

Now notice that $X_1+X_2>0$ iff $X_1=X_2=1$, so

$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq c\right)=1-P(X_1=1, X_2=1)=1-P(X_1=1) P(X_2=1)=1-\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^2=\dfrac{5}{9}>\dfrac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks. It seems to me that this argument wouldn't work anymore for $m$ and $n$ sufficiently large. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Here, I **show that the inequality in the OP holds** for the large class of [log-concave distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function), including any affine transformation of some of the following well-known distributions:

- the normal distribution
- the exponential distribution
- the uniform distribution
- the logistic distribution
- the extreme value distribution
- the Laplace distribution
- the chi distribution
- the hyperbolic secant distribution,

and many other distributions (see the link [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function)). The transformation needs to be such that the mean is zero, e.g.

$$X_1,X_2,\dots \sim a \, \mathcal E (\lambda) -\frac{a}{\lambda} + \mathcal U(-b,b) + \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)+ c\, \chi^2_k -c\, k $$

for any $a,b, c \in \mathbb R, \sigma^2>0 $.

### Proof

First consider the following two key properties for log-concave distributions [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function):

> If $X$ has a log-concave distribution $f_X$, then its cdf $F_X(x)=\mathbb P (X \le x)$ is also log-concave, that is, $\log F_X(x)$ is a concave function on its support.

> The sum of two independent random variable with log-concave distribution again has a log-concave distribution.

Hence, if $X$ has a log-concave distribution, then $\log F_{X_1+\dots +X_n}(x)$ is a concave function, where $X_1,\dots, X_n \sim X$.

The inequity in the OP for  $n>m$:

$$ P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq c \right) \leq P \left( \sum_{i=1}^m X_i \leq c \right),$$

is **equivalent to:**

$$\color{blue}{\log F_{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}(c) \leq \log F_{\sum_{i=1}^m X_i}(c)}. $$

The LHS can be written as

$$\log F_{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}(c)=\mathbb E \left [ \log F_{\sum_{i=1}^m X_i} \left (c-\sum_{i=m+1}^nX_i \right ) \right ].$$

As $\log F_{\sum_{i=m+1}^n X_i}$ is a concave function, from the [Jensen inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) we have:

$$\color{blue}{\log F_{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}(c)}=\mathbb E \left [ \log F_{\sum_{i=1}^m X_i} \left (c-\sum_{i=m+1}^nX_i \right ) \right ] \le \\ \log F_{\sum_{i=1}^m X_i} \left (\mathbb E \left [c-\sum_{i=m+1}^nX_i \right ] \right )=\color{blue}{\log F_{\sum_{i=1}^m X_i} \left (c\right )},$$

in which we used $\mathbb E \left [\sum_{i=m+1}^nX_i \right ]=0$.

Hence, the inequality not only holds for the standard normal distribution, but also holds for any other log-concave distributions with zero mean. Note that if $X,Y$ have a log-concave distribution, then for any $a,b \in \mathbb R$, the following transformation:
$$a \left (X-\mathbb E(X) \right )+b \left (Y-\mathbb E(Y) \right )$$ has a log-concave distribution whose mean is zero, e.g.,
$$X_1, X_2, \dots \sim a \, \mathcal E (\lambda) -\frac{a}{\lambda},$$
$$X_1, X_2, \dots \sim  \mathcal U (-a,a) $$
$$X_1, X_2, \dots \sim \mathcal U (-a,a)+ \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2).  $$